# is there a way to assign a type in list comprehension?

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop, list-comprehension, python-dataclasses

I'm pretty new in coding and here is my newbie question.
So, basically I had this peace of code:

```
def main():
    n = int(input())
    array = []
    for _ in range(n):
        login, solved, penalties = input().split()
        array.append(
            Participant(login, int(solved), int(penalties))
        )
    quicksort(array, 0, n-1)
    for i in array:
        print(i.login)
```

The new version I made looks like this:

```
def main():
    n: int = int(input())
    array: List[Participant] = [
        Participant(*sys.stdin.readline().split()) for _ in range(n)
    ]
    result: List[Participant] = quicksort(array, 0, n - 1)
    print(*result, sep="\n")
```

But now I get a TypeError while trying to execute a quicksort func.
`TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'str'`

Here's the full code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import sys
from typing import List


@dataclass
class Participant:
    login: str
    solved: int
    penalties: int

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (
            (-self.solved, self.penalties, self.login)
            < (-other.solved, other.penalties, other.login)
        )


def quicksort(array: list, left: int, right: int):
    if left >= right:
        return
    i, j = left, right
    pivot = array[(left + right) // 2]
    while i <= j:
        while array[i] < pivot:
            i += 1
        while array[j] > pivot:
            j -= 1
        if i <= j:
            array[i], array[j] = array[j], array[i]
            i, j = i + 1, j - 1

    quicksort(array, left, j)
    quicksort(array, i, right)


def main():
    n: int = int(input())
    array: List[Participant] = [
        Participant(*sys.stdin.readline().split()) for _ in range(n)
    ]
    result: List[Participant] = quicksort(array, 0, n - 1)
    print(*result, sep="\n")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So, the question is, can I explicitly specify types in list comprehension, if that is where my issue arises?

I tried to use Google to find similar code examples, but I couldn't find anything that would be useful in my situation.

Comment: It would certainly be *possible* to write this as a list comprehension, but it would be an unreadable mess - made complicated by the fact that only two of the three parameters to `Participant()` need to have `int()` applied to them.

Comment: you can do it like this. but I do not recommend to do it this way. It is unreadable stuff - `Participant(*[v if i == 0 else int(v) for i, v in enumerate(sys.stdin.readline().split())]) for _ in range(n)` also you do not have return in your `quicksort` function so your print will fail as it cannot unpack `NoneType`

Comment: @jasonharper this is true and I totally agree, but my person who checks my work wants me to do it this way so I have to adjust.

Comment: @pL3b works like a charm, the type error is gone, now I just have to figure out the best way to return the result of the quicksort function. Thanks.